# LVM Raid recovery

Tags: linux, raid, lvm, testdisk

Ok, I've been beating my head against a wall for 18 hours now with this HDD and cant seem to get anywhere. Heres the backstory. Have had an Iomega EZ-3 Network storage center for about 4 years now. Thing has worked 'alright' most of the time, just slow. So, the other day my dog decides to go to town on it and the chipset just stopped working (on the unit, not the drive). So I remove the drive, plug it into windows and it spins up. Of course, being windows it doesnt like it and just wants to format it. I didnt format it. I tried using some recovery software to get what I can off of it, DiskInternals can see the partitions and disk, but cant do anything with it, their recovery software ran through and found 40k files on it, but without spending 150 I can actually recover any (but the preview window did show my family pics, which is what I want the most). So I tried the Linux route with no luck. I am not a Linux person. So my limited knowledge and experience only drove my frustration further. I booted to testdisk, it saw that there is 2 LVM partitions, 2 RAID, with 1 of each being set to 'D' and two set to 'P'. I tried rewriting the P to the drive, but nothing came back up. I used Gpart, and it sees the drive, sees some small partitions (biggest being 20GB) and the rest unallocated. So I believe the drive is fine, its just the partition is missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Got years of family photos on there.

Comment: No formatting, I won't bother to read.

Comment: But you'll bother to comment...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about the filenames, `photorec` could be your answer. This comes with the `testdisk` suite, and scrapes known filetypes from a raw disk.

iomega likely had a proprietary partitioning scheme on the NAS, meaning it may not be mountable directly from an OS.

Back to `testdisk`, you don't necessarily need to write a partition table to the disk in order to recover files.

After booting up testdisk with the disk attached, select your disk and partition table. You will likely want to select 'Intel' to start. If you pick the wrong one, no problem. It can scan the drive for partition signatures.

Once you have picked up the partitions, testdisk will tell you a little about them, including partition type and stability. If they are green, they have a readable structure. Hit P to list the files of a particular partition. Deleted files will show up red. You can highlight a folder and press c to copy the files from it. It will ask you where to save it, make sure you have space somewhere. When you are done recovering, keep pressing q to quit.

Sorry if this is redundant information or something you already tried.